# Almost complex structure on $S^6$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, almost-complex

It is known that the sphere $ S^6$ admits an almost complex structure by identifying $S^6 $ with the space of unit purely imaginary Cayley numbers.

I would like to show that this almost complex structure is not integrable using the Nijenhuis tensor.

Can someone explain to me how vector fields look like in $S^6$ and how can we apply them in the Nijenhuis tensor?

I found something in Ballmann's [book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=e9mp7QXSxO8C&pg=PA17&dq=Lectures%20on%20K%C3%A4hler%20Manifolds%20cayley%20numbers&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim95TI5afSAhUD74MKHfXAC0wQ6wEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Lectures%20on%20K%C3%A4hler%20Manifolds%20cayley%20numbers&f=false) (Kahler manifolds) but I didn't understand it.

Comment: Could you explain more details which part you do not follow in Ballmann's book?

Comment: How he defines the vector fields and how he calculates the tensor? Actually I need to understand everything in order to show it is not integrable